# Can't use vis with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, vis.js

I'm trying to add [`vis.js`](http://visjs.org/) to a 4-year-old web application.

When I run the application without packaging everything, it works. However, when I package everything with `grunt`, I get the following error in the browser's console:

> Mismatched anonymous define() module

When I comment out the code

```
require(['vis'], function(vis)) { ... }
```

The error disappears, but obviously I don't have any access to vis any more.

I seem to be doing everything that is shown in [the example](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/examples/timeline/other/requirejs/scripts/main.js) , with the exception of using `data-main` when loading require.js. That's because it is no longer supported by use-min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with other library (NanoModal). The only solution which worked for me was to exclude that library from packaging using the `paths` configuration of the `r.js` optimizer:

```
paths: {
   "nanomodal": "empty:"
}
```

Comment: How can I require a module if requirejs can't find it?

Comment: That's only for r.js optimizer configuration used during build.

Comment: @zmbq I cannot tell whether this answer would fix your issue, but in general it is fine to set a module as empty for the purpose of building. What this means is that RequireJS will have to seek the module from some another source than the bundle your produce with `r.js`. The post-build configuration has to be set up to allow RequireJS to find the module.